# how to create 2 variable session in Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

How to Create 2 variable session 
I have create but for $se not show

[image]

Comment: Before getting any down vote,improve your answer to explain your question clearly and share what you have done so far

Comment: You should re edit your question by clicking on edit button below tags and and code you have got in image rather than just pasting image.

Answer (score 0):

I think your after something like Multiple session but question unclear

Examples

Backend

```
$session_vals1 = array(
   'some_data' => 1
);

$this->session->set_userdata('backend', $session_vals1);
```

To access

```
$session_vals1_data = $this->session->userdata('backend');

echo $session_vals1_data['some_data'];
```

Frontend

```
$session_vals2 = array(
   'some_data' => 2
);

$this->session->set_userdata('frontend', $session_vals1);
```

To access

```
$session_vals1_data = $this->session->userdata('frontend');

echo $session_vals1_data['some_data'];
```